What is the correct translation of Habakkuk 1:12?
What is the correct translation of Habakkuk 1:12?
Habakkuk 1:12
Complete Jewish Bible
Adonai, haven’t you existed forever?
My God, my holy one, we will not die.
Habakkuk 1:12
King James Version
12 Art thou not from everlasting, O Lord my God, mine Holy One? we shall not die.
OR
Habakkuk 1:12
Holman Christian Standard Bible
Are You not from eternity, Yahweh my God?
My Holy One, You will not die.
Habakkuk 1:11-13
Lexham English Bible
Are you not from of old,
O Yahweh my God, my Holy One?
You shall not die.
Is it "we" or "you"?

I think this should be asked on BHSE.

Biblehub Interlinear shows the verb to be first person plural. Both Young's Literal and Green's Literal have 'we'. Up-voted +1.

The operative word in the Hebrew is נָמ֑וּת = "we die" because it is a Verb, Qal-imperfect in the 1st person common plural.
As support for this I quote the following:

the LXX says: Are you not from the beginning, O Lord God, my Holy One? and surely we shall not die. O Lord, thou hast established it for judgment, and he has formed me to chasten with his correction.
DRB/Vulgate: Wast thou not from the beginning, O Lord my God, my holy one, and we shall not die? Lord, thou hast appointed him for judgment: and made him strong for correction.
JPS/TLV, CJB.
All literal versions such as ESV, BSB, NKJV, NASB, LSB, ASV, ERV, ISV, LSV, YLT, etc.
While the NIV has "You will not die", a footnote says this reading is a scribal tradition, and that the actual text says, "we will not die".

However, we have the helpful comments of the Cambridge commentary on Hab 1:12 -

According to Jewish tradition “we shall not die” is a tiḳḳun
(emendation) of the “scribes” for thou shall not die (diest not).
Opinions differ as to who the “scribes” are. Some consider that the
original authors are meant, in which case the tiḳḳun would be a second
thought of the writer. What occurred to him to say first was “thou
diest not,” but reverence restrained him from bringing the ideas of
death and God together, and he said “we shall not die.” We are not
informed how this interesting process in the prophet’s mind became
known to after-times. Obviously this is not the real account of the
matter, which is not easy to give. No doubt, however, these so-called
emendations—there are eighteen of them—were either (1) real
corrections by the scribes, i.e. copyists or editors of the sacred
books; or (2) they are no emendations at all, but the original text;
the supposed readings which they are said to have supplanted being
mere fancies of Jewish scholars as to what might have been written.
Possibly they are partly of the one class and partly of the other. In
the present passage Sept. agrees with Heb., but in another, Job 7:20,
it exhibits the supposed original reading: “I am become a burden unto
Thee” (Heb. unto myself).

Concerning the 18 emendations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiqqun_soferim
Thus, "we shall not die" is the Masoretic text; but the scribal tradition appears to want to emend this to "You [ie, YHWH] shall not die."
I personally believe the text should be left alone and translated as it is.
